# Sending currency symbol from php to flash

Tags: php, javascript, flash

I am having many websites . In that I have to send some parameters from php to flash. All the parameters are getting correctly displayed in flash except the currency symbol. These currency symbols are extracted from db to php in form of html entities like(& pound;). I can't change the db as it will require many changes in all websites of mine. I have used rawurlencode in php before sending to flash but in flash it gets displayed as & pound; in flash. I have given space between "&" and "pound;" so it is not converted to symbol in the post . In db it is correctly entered with no space. Previously , I was sending directly by writing the object tag in php file and and writing the parameters in params tag withing object tag. It was working perfectly fine . Now I have start using swfobject.js javascript library of hosted by google for embedding the flash content. Now its not working ( currency symbol is not getting displayed instead it html entity unicode shown above is getting displayed.) . I can't change the flash files also. I have to handle it from php or javascript code only.

Comment: Well, what is not working? What happens?

Comment: In the flash file , pound symbol is getting displayed as html entity . It is not getting converted to symbol .

Comment: Flash doesn't automatically convert HTML entities (since it is not a HTML renderer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's encoded with htmlentities(), just decode it before sending to flash(and of course before re-encoding with rawurlencode) by using [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it is working using html_entity_decode.